# How can I write a Ruby class to hold a pair or items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

Here is what I have so far, it is not working:

```
class Couple(o,t)
  one = o
  two = t
end

couple1 = Couple.new(10, "Ten")
p couple1.one
p couple1.two
```

Not sure why it's not working?

Comment: Surely will, I am just starting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Defining a class doesn't work like defining functions, you have to define functions on them that use the internal variables, and the the initializer that tells it what to do when calling .new

attr_accessor helps with the crud of setting up the functions and variables. The most simplest ways would be to use have a class like

```
class Couple
  attr_accessor :one, :two
end

couple1 = Couple.new
couple1.one = 10
couple1.two = "Ten"
p couple1.one
p couple1.two
```

To use the new function to `initialize` the class with a few variables, you can define that function giving you a Class definition looking like

```
class Couple
  attr_accessor :one, :two

  def initialize(one, two)
    @one = one
    @two = two
  end
end

couple1 = Couple.new(10, "Ten")
p couple1.one
p couple1.two
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to just hold a pair of items, then use Struct. It's a simple generator of classes that contain only variables and accessors, and nothing else (similar co C/C++'s Struct).

```
Couple = Struct.new(:one, :two)

# Or more idiomatically
class Couple < Struct.new(:one, :two)
  def to_s
    "one: #{self.one}, two: #{self.two}"
  end
end

couple1 = Couple.new(10, 'ten')
puts couple1  # one: 10, two: ten

couple1.one = 100
puts couple1  # one: 100, two: ten
```

Also, one very interesting thing in Ruby is that the class data/members, both instance and class/static ones are "private" -- you can access them from outside only via accessor methods, not directly, and Ruby gives you the possibility to quicky generate these methods with the macros `atrr_accessor`, `attr_reader`, and `attr_writer`.

```
class Couple
  one = 'o'
  two = 't'
end

p Couple.one  # NoMethodError: undefined method `one' for Couple:Class


class Couple
  def initialize(one, two)
    @one = one
    @two = two
  end
end

c = Couple.new(10, 'ten')
p c.one  # undefined method `one' for #<Couple:0x936d2d4 @one=10, @two="ten">
```

That's why you need the accessors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `attr_reader` for read or `attr_accessor` for read/write to access the class variables.  Your class should look like this:

```
class Couple
  attr_accessor :one, :two

  def initialize(one, two)
    @one = one
    @two = two
  end
end
```

Using `attr_accessor` will create, in this case, the methods `one, one=, two, two=`.  If you were to use `attr_reader`, it would create the methods `one, two`.

Using the example above code, you could have:

```
couple = Couple.new(5, 6)
p couple.one # Outputs 5
p couple.two # Outputs 6
couple.one = 7
p couple.one # Outputs 7
```

There is also `attr_writer`, which will give you the methods `one=, two=`, but this isn't what you're looking for in this case.  It gives you write only access to a variable.